# Guarantee of generating set spanning the whole subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose that I have a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is restricted by a single equation on the components of ordered $n$-tuples within that space. I find a set $S$ of $n-1$ linearly independent vectors. Is there any persuasive argument (i. e. theorem I could make use of) to guarantee that $Sp(S) = V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V \neq \mathbb{R}^n$, it must be $$\dim V <\dim \mathbb{R}^n = n$$ Since $V$ contains the linearly independent set $S$, we have $$\dim V \ge \mathrm{card}\, S = n - 1$$
Hence, $\dim V = n- 1$.

A theorem you could now use is this one:

> Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional vector space such that $\dim X = k$. Let $A \subset X$ be a linearly independent subset of $X$ with $\mathrm{card}\, A = k$. Then $\mathrm{span}\,A = X$, so $A$ is a basis for $X$.

$S$ has $n-1$ elements, the same as the dimension of $V$, so $\mathrm{span}\,S = V$.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the literature for our course mentiones no such fact. I guess I'll have to look further.

Comment: @user35443 The proof is not difficult: assume $A$ doesn't span $X$. Then $A$, as a linearly independent set, can be extended to a basis $B \supset A$ for $X$. But then we would have $\mathrm{card}\,B > \mathrm{card}\,A = \dim X$, so $B$ would have greater cardinality than the dimension of $X$.